# How to lock localStorage to update from Browser Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, locking

I wanted to secure my web app. 
I'm storing some data like user session using `localStorage`.
I noticed that anyone can update data `localStorage` from Console.

I found few ways but it's not working as expected!. here below code I have tried.

#### Override 'setItem' function

```
var localSetItem = localStorage.setItem;
localStorage.setItem = function () {
    // don't allow to rewrite localStorage object
    if (arguments[0] == "UserDetails" && localStorage.UserDetails)
        return;
    document.createEvent('Event').initEvent('itemInserted', true, true);
    localSetItem.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Issue with this

> I can prevent when use `localStorage.setItem('UserDetails', {...})` but it will not call when set by `localStorage.UserDetails = {...}`

#### set 'addEventListener'

```
window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('UserDetails')));
});
```

Issue with this

> for some reason addEventListener is not call on change

#### set 'defineProperty'

```
Object.defineProperty(localStorage, 'UserDetails', {
  get: function () { return localStorage.UserDetails; },
  set: function (v) {
    console.error('this object is read only!');
  }
});
```

Issue with this

> `Object.defineProperty(localStorage,...` getting error "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set a named property on 'Storage': Accessor properties are not allowed."

Comment: You can't stop the user modifying any part of the DOM or any data stored on the client side (ie cookies, local or session storage). What you are attempting to do is pointless. You need to secure everything on the server side, and make sure every user interaction is authenticated and validated so that it does not violate strict domain rules.

Comment: localStorage or sessionStorage should not be used to store sensitive information. Anything you store there you should be fine with users viewing.

Comment: yeah i know, I have some data from server side.
but for performance issue. i'm try to lock this if possible

Comment: consider as I'm storing simple value just don't wanted to update by browser console

Comment: Even if you forget about the console, there are still numerous other ways to execute code (like Tempermonkey), and as the name implies, localStorage is stored on the users computer so at the end of the day there will always be a way for them to access/modify it. This is one of those cases where you want to disable built-in browser functionality (like sites that disable right-clicks). And in almost every situation, you shouldn't be disabling said functionality.